# Detect location.hash change when ancor is not clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url, location

after 2 days googling i cannot come out of this problem..
I have a complete ajax site and i need make back button working. Actual situation is that i can handle event when changing history status with this code

```
window.onpopstate = function(e){
   //ajax call here
}
```

The problem is that the function is right called when i press the back button but is called twice when i click on my ancor's menu. This is why i have anchor function to use normal ajax calling:

```
$("#home").click(function(){            
        load_right_container('home.php');
        location.hash = "!home";           
        return false;
    });
```

Obviously changing location.has activate even window.onpopstate so i have double loading of the page.

My idea is to call the ajax load only if an anchor is not clicked and location.hash changes, something like:

```
if( window.onpopstate && !($('a').click())
{ //ajax call here}
```

But is not working.

Any advice?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**

Maybe the question is not clear: 
Does exist a way to get **only back button pressure** without passing trought location.hash change?

Comment: `$(window).on('hashchange', function() { ...`

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue?

Comment: No, i cant fiddle it, is too difficult. @adeneo your solution is same as mine, i dont need detecting haschange, i need detecting haschange when press back button but not when i click on anchor